# Table missing in dba_objects and dba_tab_columns

Tags: oracle

I have a oracle database where some tables which are present in dba_tables are not present in dba_objects and dba_tab_columns. Can anyone help me understand why there is mismatch between these three metadata tables ?

Comment: How do you find them? Please show at least a couple of examples?  I know just one exclusion - `SYS."_default_auditing_options_"`

Comment: Can you post a test case?  Or at least show us the results of the queries?

Comment: and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean SYS."*default_auditing_options*":

```
SQL> select owner,table_name from dba_tables
     minus 
     select owner,object_name from dba_objects where object_type='TABLE';

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            _default_auditing_options_
```

That is an internal special oracle table, read this doc:
[Why Do DBA_TABLES DBA_OBJECTS And DBA_SEGMENTS Differ When Selected For Tables? (Doc ID 363048.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=363048.1#FIX)

Comment: Sayan, Not system tables, there are few other user tables which are present in dba_tables but not in dba_objects and dba_tab_columns

Comment: @maseedilyas show how do you check it and what exactly do you get. If that's not `_default_auditing_options_` then it looks like a bug and you need to provide more info to troubleshoot it.